# How do I intercept the post-deserialized request object in WCF

Tags: wcf, request, interceptor

I need to intercept WCF requests for all of our web services. All of the services follow a strict model where the operations must take a single request that extends from our base request type. That base request type carries attributes we need for various system level support, custom logging is one, but there are many others. I was hoping to use IDispatchMessageInspector, but I don't see how I can get the request object from the "message" without having to recreate a copy from the body. I need this to be efficient, so creating two copies each request won't cut it.

I know I can create proxies with System.Reflection.Emit, but that'll get mixed up with service activation and factories...i was hoping for something more readily available, like the way CXF interceptors work for Java.

Is there anyway I can intercept the actual single request instance in the server, just before being dispatched to the service impl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Message inspector is for working with messages not with parameters. For working with deserialized objects you need parameter inspector (implements [IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx)).

Comment: Works perfectly fine, exactly what I needed.